# Finding the location of maximum peaks in a plot with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, location, max

Suppose I have the F matrix like this:

```
F =
0, 0, 106, 10, 14, 20, 20, 23, 27, 26, 28, 28, 28, 23
       |                        |           |
     peak                     peak         peak
```

I'm using the command `plot(F)`. I want to get the indexes of the peaks in the data.

This is the code I have so far, it does not work:

```
[max_x,index_x]=max(x);
e=index_x;
for i=1:11
    index_x(i)=e;
    e=e+16;
end
```

Is there a builtin function in matlab that will do this for me?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [findpeaks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) function (Signal Processing Toolbox).

```
[peakVal,peakLoc]= findpeaks(x);
```

Comment: @@kl3755, I've added an example for the answer I'm looking for. I hope it could clarify a bit.

Comment: @user2201486 use the optional `'threshold'` or `'minpeakheight'` arguments if you wish the peaks to have a minimum height.

Comment: @erikced I want to have all "x" value of absolute peaks.   like what it is shown in an instance at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is what I prefer:

```
[maxval maxloc] = max(A(:));
```

Comment: To make this a better answer, can you please explain why you prefer that, pros/cons etc.? Thanks!