# finding minimum reflection points using matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a dataset the red line.
I'm trying to find the minimum points **highlighted in yellow** if I take the reflection/mirror image of a data set.

See example code / plot below I'm trying to find a way to find the minimum points **highlighted in yellow** of the reflection/mirror image of a dataset **(the blue line)** that is below the reflection line **(the black line)**.

Please note this is just a simple dataset there will be much larger datasets around 100000+

PS: I'm using Octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab

```
clear all,clf, clc,tic

x1=[0.;2.04;4.08;6.12;8.16;10.2;12.24;14.28;16.32;18.36]
y1=[2;2.86;4;2;1;4;5;2;7;1]
x2=[0.;2.04;4.08;6.12;8.16;10.2;12.24;14.28;16.32;18.36]
y2=abs(y1-max(y1));
data1 = y2; 
reflection_line=max(y1)/2
[pks3 idx3] = findpeaks(data1,"DoubleSided","MinPeakHeight",0.1);

line([min(x1) max(x1)], [reflection_line reflection_line]);
hold on;
plot(x1,reflection_line)
hold on;
plot(x1,y1,'-r',x2,y2,'-b')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: you don't have to build the full reflected line, just find the max of the original dataset _above_ the reflection line, then only "reflect" the found points.

Comment: And to find these max, use `findpeaks` from the `signal` package. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15584033/3565696).

Comment: @Hoki using max only gives me the max which is one point.

Comment: @huntj if I use findpeaks like you mentioned it will give me extra peaks not just the minimum ones that are below the reflection line.

Comment: @RickT Even with the `MinPeakHeight` option ?

Comment: @huntj I tried
 [pks3 idx3] = findpeaks(data1,"DoubleSided","MinPeakHeight",0.1); and I didn't get the three values I was looking for...I'll update the question with it

Comment: Is this the same as finding only those local maxima of the red line, that are above your *reflection line*?

Comment: @knedlsepp in this example i kept the example very simple the actually data is going to be around 400000 data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not reflecting your original data, but rather find the local maxima of the original values, that are larger than your given line.

Using a DIY alternative to `findpeaks`:
A value is a local maximum, if it's larger than (or equal to) its predecessor and successor.

```
%% Setup
x1 = [0.;2.04;4.08;6.12;8.16;10.2;12.24;14.28;16.32;18.36];
y1 = [2;2.86;4;2;1;4;5;2;7;1];
reflection_line = max(y1)/2;
%% Sort by x value
[x1, I] = sort(x1);
y1 = y1(I);
%% Compute peaks
maxima = @(y) [true; y(2:end)>=y(1:end-1)] & ... % Value larger than predecessor
              [y(1:end-1)>=y(2:end); true];      % Value larger than successor
maximaLargerThanLine =  maxima(y1) & (y1>reflection_line);
%% Plotting
plot(x1,y1);
hold on;
plot(x1(maximaLargerThanLine),y1(maximaLargerThanLine),'rx');
line([min(x1) max(x1)], [reflection_line reflection_line]);
```